# Change amplitude of sine wave to fit into AudioTrack.write(array: FloatArray) method

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an education app that can combine simple waves and play them.
There is a method in AudioTrack that accepts an array of floats(from docs):

```
     *     audioData the array that holds the data to write.
     *     The implementation does not clip for sample values within the nominal range
     *     [-1.0f, 1.0f], provided that all gains in the audio pipeline are
     *     less than or equal to unity (1.0f), and in the absence of post-processing effects
     *     that could add energy, such as reverb.  For the convenience of applications
     *     that compute samples using filters with non-unity gain,
     *     sample values +3 dB beyond the nominal range are permitted.
     *     However such values may eventually be limited or clipped, depending on various gains
     *     and later processing in the audio path.  Therefore applications are encouraged
     *     to provide samples values within the nominal range.

           public int write(@NonNull float[] audioData, ...)
```

Which stands that I should use floats in between `[-1.0f, 1.0f]`
When generating a complex sine wave I add two of them together, which increases my range to `[-2.0f, 2.0f]` 
I think I should somehow *normalize* this...

```
private fun playSound(frequency1: Float, frequency2: Float) {
        val sineWave = FloatArray(BUFFER_SIZE) //data array
        val period1 = SAMPLING_RATE / frequency1
        val period2 = SAMPLING_RATE / frequency2
        for (i in sineWave.indices) {
            sineWave[i] = Math.sin(Math.PI * i / period1).toFloat() +
                Math.sin(Math.PI * i / period2).toFloat()
        }
        player.setVolume(0.5f)
        player.write(sineWave, 0, sineWave.size, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING)
        player.play()
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is a correct thing, so I need some help with creating complex sine waves

Comment: Don't change the volume; that doesn't change the clipping limit of the waves. Just divide the value of sineWave[i] by the number of waves.

Comment: @greeble31 that was pretty obvious, and I thought too easy. I thought there might be some normalization function...